# Checking multiple values and displaying errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I frequently have to check multiple similar fields, first to see if there's a problem in either, then to see which one(s) contain invalid data. Is there a better way to do this than what I have here?

I'm interested both in the programming theory and in javascript specifically.

```
if(($("#movie1").val() == "")||($("#movie2").val() == "")) {
    if($("#movie1").val() == "") {
        $("#movie1error").show();
    }

    if($("#movie2").val() == "") {
        $("#movie2error").show();
    }
}
else {
    //success
}
```

Comment: "displaying errors" ? So what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `class` selectors instead of checking with ids if the task is similar. Add a common class to the fields you want to check. Say the class name is `myCheck`
Then with jQuery you could do the following

```
$('.myCheck').each(function(index,value){
    if(!$(this).val()){
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'error').show();
    }
});
```

Also you could specify a common class for your error element also

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BTu76/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `||` instead of `&&`. Also you need to use `val()` instead of `value()`

```
var isMovie1Empty = $("#movie1").val() == "";
var isMovie2Empty = $("#movie2").val() == "";
if (isMovie1Empty || isMovie2Empty) {
    if (isMovie1Empty) {
        $("#movie1error").show();
    }
    if (isMovie2Empty) {
        $("#movie2error").show();
    }
} else {
    //success
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery has no method `value()` over objects changes it to `val()` . Your algorithm is correct i think and use `or`  intead of `and`   operator to connect the conditions

```
if(($("#movie1").val() == "")||($("#movie2").val() == "")) {
    if($("#movie1").val() == "") {
        $("#movie1error").show();
    }

    if($("#movie2").val() == "") {
        $("#movie2error").show();
    }
}
else {
    //success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#movie1").val() === "" && $("#movie2").val() === "") {

    if ($("#movie1").val() === "") {
        $("#movie1error").show();
    }

    if ($("#movie2").val() === "") {
        $("#movie2error").show();
    }
} else {
    alert("success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i always use something like this:

```
function fieldsOk(){
switch(true){
    case ($("#txt1").val() == ""):
        return false;
    case ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2")):
        return false;
}
return true;
}

if(fieldsOk()){
 // code here
}else{
// show error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, empty strings will be treated the same way as `false` is in an if-statement. Instead of testing it against an empty string, you can also simply put a NOT `!` in front of it.

Furthermore, you don't need the surrounding test if both are errors, and then also have a test if either is an error. So, if you want to show the error of the movie that has an empty string as value, you can do the following:

```
if (!$('#movie1').val()) $('movie1error').show();
else if (!$('#movie2').val()) $('movie2error').show();
else {
    //success
}
```

*Note:* I didn't put `{}` around the code to show the errors, since it's only a single thing you do when you get the empty string, so you don't need those in this case. If you want to start doing more when you get an empty string, you should put those around the code though.

If you want both errors to show only if both movies are an empty string, you can change that to:

```
if (!$('#movie1').val() && !$('#movie2').val()) {
    $('movie1error').show();
    $('movie2error').show();
} else {
    //success
}
```

Comment: @Satpal oh yes I just copied over the code from the question. Fixed it.

Comment: The first code block you posted will only show one error; the second will only show if both are wrong. I want to tell the user if one or both contain errors.